# How to rename activity_main.xml after starting a new basic activity project?

Tags: android

Whenever I try to refactor activity_main.xml after creating a new project it tells me: "These files do not belong to the project" and lists package-info.java and textview.java as non project files that must be altered.

Can anyone tell me how to do this without messing up essential files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the proper steps:

Step 1, right-click on activity_main, -> Refactor -> rename

Step 2, write new name:

[image]

Step 3, Do Refactor, after this if you see any prompt box.. select "project only".

[image]

Changed name:

[image]

Comment: Hi sir. I can choose "Project Files" in the "Scope" menu in the first refactor prompt. Afterward, even with "Referenes in code..." selected, it still wants to change external files.